# MPMoivePlayer Video Play in Background

Tags: audio, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play the Audio of video in the Background..

I m using MPMoivePlayerController..

How can i Solve that  ?

Please Help me..

thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

MpMoviePlayer doesn't supported, you must try AvPlayer..

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html